# Node.js response.end([data], [encoding]) method

Tags: node.js, http, syntax, parameter-passing

The documentation for the method writes, 
"If data is specified, it is equivalent to calling response.write(data, encoding) followed by response.end()."

And the doc describes the response.write(chunk, [encoding]) as,

chunk can be a string or a buffer. If chunk is a string, the second parameter specifies how to encode it into a byte stream. By default the encoding is 'utf8'.

I still do not get how to use this method given the description. Can someone give a very simple example of a set of working parameters in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.end(data, encoding)` will do the following:

```
response.write(data, encoding);
response.end();
```

Sample code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });

    // 1st way
    response.write('Hello World\n');
    response.end();

    // 2nd way, equivalent
    //response.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log('running');
```

Answer (score 1):

hm, simple:

`res.write('<h1>It works!</h1>', 'utf8');`

`res.end();`

is equivalent to

`res.end('<h1>It works!</h1>', 'utf8');`